# Future "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr<UserModel>',

Tags: string, flutter, authentication

```
  Future<UserModel> register({
required String name,
required String username,
required String email,
required String password,
```

}) async {

Future "The body might complete normally, causing 'null' to be returned, but the return type, 'FutureOr',

Comment: Can you include full method

Answer (score 1):

As for the error message, this method can return null. You can convert return data type to nullable.

```dart
  Future<UserModel?> register({
```

More about [understanding-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety)